# When to use hard vs soft side of mallet?

Tags: hand-tools

I have a mallet like this:
[image]

I do plenty with it, like hammer in dowels, persuade woodworking joints to close, and other random things. However, I never have a reason for which side I use. They both seem to do the same job of "non-marring force application". After lots of googling I didn't find any kinds of rules of thumb or lists of jobs to be done with each side. Is there a rationale that should be applied using one or the other of these heads?

Comment: The only difference is the soft side can handle sheet metal works, while the hard side may cause damages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estwing

> The premium-priced Estwing Rubber Mallet is just 12 ounces in weight but can be used effectively on a range of tough projects, including sheet metal forming, upholstery work, and automotive repair. The mallet’s two rubber heads allow it to deliver this impressive range. **There is one soft rubber head for lighter materials and one hard rubber head for firmer materials.** The double-face rubber mallet has a high-quality, curved hickory handle explicitly contoured to fit the grip of your hand. This ensures you have optimal control over the head of the mallet when you swing. This mallet has a smooth wood finish that gives it a natural appearance that looks great in any workshop.

Tekton

> The small, 12-ounce TEKTON Double-Face Rubber Mallet isn’t designed to strike incredibly hard, as a larger mallet would, but the two unique faces of the mallet allow it to be used in a wide variety of jobs and with a variety of materials. **You’ll find the mallet’s soft rubber face is ideal for hammering lightweight materials or delivering firm blows to fragile materials. The mallet’s hard rubber face is intended for work with hardwoods and solid metal pieces that need a hard but forgiving surface.** The double-face mallet handle is made of durable, lightweight tubular steel, which effectively shifts the mallet’s balance toward the head. This shift in balance allows you to swing the mallet more effectively in a tight space. One word of caution: The design can also increase fatigue if you don’t properly control the mallet. Tekton designed this rubber mallet with a soft, rubber grip to enhance control and absorb impact vibration.

Source: https://www.bobvila.com/articles/best-rubber-mallet/

Googling methodology: "woodworking hard versus soft mallet"

---

Basically, if you're damaging your material then use the softer side.